# How do I right align controls in a TTTableControlItem?

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm using Three20's TTTableViewController to display a sectioned table view.  The datasource is a TTSectionedDataSource containing TTTableControlItems.  The controls are all left aligned.  I'd like to make them right aligned.  Is there any way to do this without creating a custom cell?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make a sub-class. Information how to make it is here: http://blog.whirix.com/2010/06/customizing-tttablemessageitem.html